# get function ptr to member function of instanced class?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

```
class gfx { 
    void resize(int x, int y);
}

gfx g;
```

can i cast g.resize to a 'void (*)(int, int)' somehow?

Comment: If you explain what you are trying to do, perhaps we can suggest some alternatives that will work.

Comment: wrap a resize callback in GLFW into my graphics class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. `gfx::resize` is of type `void(gfx::*)(int, int)`.  You can't meaningfully convert it to type `void(*)(int, int)` because you can only call it as a member function on an object of type `gfx`.

A member function can only be called on an instance of the class, so given your `gfx g;`, you can call `g.resize()`, but you can't just call `resize()` like it were an ordinary function.  An ordinary function pointer can't point to a member function because it doesn't have any way to bind the function call to an instance of the class.

Conceptually, a member function takes an additional parameter, the `this` parameter, that points to the instance of the class on which it was called.

If you want to be able to call a member function via an ordinary function pointer, you can create a nonmember function (or a static member function) wrapper with a parameter to which you can pass the instance of the object on which to call the member function.  For example, you could have:

```
void resize(gfx* obj, int x, int y) {
    return obj->resize(x, y);
}
```

This nonmember `resize` function has type `void(*)(gfx*, int, int)` and can be called as a nonmember function.  The generalized form of this approach is the `std::function` and `std::bind` facilities found in C++0x (you can also find them in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/function.html) and in C++ TR1).

Comment: `void(*)(int, int)` doesn't have a `this` pointer.  You have to specify which type/instance you want to run it against, and so the signature must also change.

Comment: @Merlyn:  Isn't that what I said?

Comment: Yes.  Back in the day, I didn't get that "member function" took a "this" pointer.  It took me reading tutorials that were explicit about `this` for me to understand that.  Btw, I did upvote.

Comment: @Merlyn:  Ah; thank you.  I have difficulty at times thinking "like a beginner," and it's helpful that you point that out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it:

```
void easy_resize(int x, int y) { g.resize(x, y); }
```

Comment: Thats how I'm am doing it at the moment. but i have to keep track of a pointer to my graphics class which seems a bit hacky

Comment: What do you need the graphics class for? Is it necessary to make it a class? Sometimes just having functions (not member functions of a class) is a good alternative.